# SpringBoot Openshift POST io.undertow.util.ParameterLimitException: UT000047: The number of parameters exceeded the maximum of 1000

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, http-post, openshift, undertow

I have a spring boot application that is deployed on RedHat OpenShift. Whenever I have a large POST request (~11000 lines) I get this message.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.undertow.util.ParameterLimitException: UT000047: The number of parameters exceeded the maximum of 1000
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormData.add(FormData.java:95) ~[undertow-core-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormData.add(FormData.java:85) ~[undertow-core-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormEncodedDataDefinition$FormEncodedDataParser.doParse(FormEncodedDataDefinition.java:173) ~[undertow-core-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormEncodedDataDefinition$FormEncodedDataParser.parseBlocking(FormEncodedDataDefinition.java:252) ~[undertow-core-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:825) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getParameter(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:704) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:161) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar!/:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:84) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) ~[undertow-core-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) ~[undertow-core-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.GracefulShutdownHandler.handleRequest(GracefulShutdownHandler.java:69) ~[undertow-core-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292) [undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) [undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138) [undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135) [undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) [undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) [undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272) [undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) [undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104) [undertow-servlet-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364) [undertow-core-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830) [undertow-core-2.0.21.Final.jar!/:2.0.21.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292]
```

The request json is parsed in a request object that have 3 lists. And those 3 list does not exceed 1000 elements even if those are grouped by.

It does not even enters in controller.

I tried to add in yml file this property but the json file saved have 245kb and even with this property it does not run.

```
server:
  tomcat:
    max-http-post-size: 100000000 # max-http-form-post-size: 10MB for new version
```

and I also found a property for standalone.xml file but I do not know how to include it in yml file

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-parameters="5000"/>
```

Thank you

Comment: The error you see is not caused by an `application/json` request, but by an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request with more than a thousand parameters. If you didn't generate the request yourself, it might very well be malicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're using undertow server, so instead of `server.tomcat.max-http-post-size` property, try to use:

`server.undertow.max-http-post-size` instead.

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html) you can find a list of all undertow properties which could be configured through spring application file(just search for `undertow`). Here are some of them:

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| server.undertow.max-cookies | Maximum number of cookies that are allowed. This limit exists to prevent hash collision based DOS attacks. |
| server.undertow.max-headers | Maximum number of headers that are allowed. This limit exists to prevent hash collision based DOS attacks. |
| server.undertow.max-parameters | Maximum number of query or path parameters that are allowed. This limit exists to prevent hash collision based DOS attacks. |